# I would like to use vertical dots to indicate I am omitting arrows

Tags: arrows, xy-pic, stacking-symbols

I have a diagram with many parallel arrows between objects in XYpic. Eventually, they become too numerous to all display. I would like to indicate this with two outside horizontal arrows and some \vdots. To indicate in a crude picture, what I want is roughly thus:

```
-------> 
   .   
   .
   .
------->
```

in the space usually occupied by an \ar[r]. Is this achievable in XYpic? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option seems to be to create an empty arrow and put a `\vdots` at its center. You can get an empty arrow with `\ar@{}`, so this would be done with `\ar@{}[r]|\vdots`.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix@R=0.3cm{
    A\ar[r]^f & B\\
    C\ar[r]^g & D\\
    E\ar@{}[r]|\vdots & F\\
    G\ar@{}[r]|\vdots & H\\
    I\ar[r]_h & J
}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any idea how you would get it to vertically or horizontally center-align?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\vdots`, you can put an arrow consisting entirely of dots (no arrowhead, no tail) starting a bit to the right and below the upper left entry and ending a bit to the right and above the lower left entry, as in

```
Here's some text to show the margins. Here's some text to show the
margins. Here's some text to show the margins. Here's some text to 
show the margins. Here's some text to show the margins.
\begin{displaymath}
  \xymatrix@C=5em{
    {A_{1}} \ar@{-->}[r] \ar@{..}[]+<3.5em,-2ex>;[ddddd]+<3.5em,2ex>
    & {B_{1}}\\
    {A_{2}} & {B_{2}}\\
    {A_{3}} & {B_{3}}\\
    {A_{4}} & {B_{4}}\\
    {A_{5}} & {B_{5}}\\
    {A_{6}} \ar@{-->}[r] & {B_{6}}
    }
\end{displaymath}
```

That will produce

[image]